# emacs org-agenda - missing all the daily details for tasks

Tags: emacs, org-mode

For emacs25 (emacs 25.2.2 on ubuntu 17.10), I am not able to get *org-agenda-list* working. *org-timeline* shows me details on a daily basis, but *org-agenda-list* just lists the names of the days and there are no details listed.

I have the following .emacs (simplified down to one line to track down why org-agenda is not working - I know emacs reasonably well, but I am a first time user of org-mode)

```
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
```

and with an empty .emacs.d directory, when I run *org-agenda-list* for the following example:

```
* Tasks
** DONE [#A] do this y'day
SCHEDULED: <2018-03-22 Thu>
** TODO [#A] do this tomorrow
SCHEDULED: <2018-03-24 Sat>
** TODO [#A] this task is not scheduled
** TODO [#B] scheduled for today, priority B
SCHEDULED: <2018-03-23 Fri>
** IN PROGRESS [#A] scheduled today and deadline in 2 days
DEADLINE: <2018-03-25 Sun> SCHEDULED: <2018-03-23 Fri>
** TODO [#A] deadline in 2 days and not scheduled
DEADLINE: <2018-03-25 Sun>
** TODO [#A] scheduled for monday
SCHEDULED: <2018-03-29 Thu>
** TODO [#C] do this today if I get time
SCHEDULED: <2018-03-23 Fri>
** TODO [#B] neither is this one
** TODO [#C] or this one
** TODO [#A] deadline in 10 days and not scheduled
DEADLINE: <2018-03-31 Sat>
```

I only see the week entries and it is missing all the details for the daily tasks

```
Week-agenda (W12):
Monday     19 March 2018 W12
Tuesday    20 March 2018
Wednesday  21 March 2018
Thursday   22 March 2018
Friday     23 March 2018
Saturday   24 March 2018
Sunday     25 March 2018
```

Where as *org-timeline* shows me the details for the daily tasks

```
Thursday   22 March 2018
  Scheduled:  DONE [#A] do this y'day
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Friday     23 March 2018
  Scheduled:  IN PROGRESS [#A] scheduled today and deadline in 2 days
  Scheduled:  TODO [#B] scheduled for today, priority B
  Scheduled:  TODO [#C] do this today if I get time
Saturday   24 March 2018
  Scheduled:  TODO [#A] do this tomorrow
Sunday     25 March 2018
  Deadline:   IN PROGRESS [#A] scheduled today and deadline in 2 days
  Deadline:   TODO [#A] deadline in 2 days and not scheduled

[... 4 empty days omitted]

Thursday   29 March 2018
  Scheduled:  TODO [#A] scheduled for monday
Friday     30 March 2018
Saturday   31 March 2018
  Deadline:   TODO [#A] deadline in 10 days and not scheduled
```

Q: How do I get *org-agenda-list* to work properly for me ?

Moreover after I installed

```
M-x package-install org-edna
```

based on some online advice, I also lost the *org-timeline* command, which I recovered via brute-force application of "apt remove emacs" and "apt install emacs".

Q: Can anyone explain to me why I had lost the *org-timeline* command ?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you get with `M-x org-agenda <ret>` ?

Comment: Check : C-h v org-agenda-files.   If your file is not there use :  M-x  org-agenda-file-to-front.

Comment: @manandearth that gives the standard message:

    "Press key for an agenda command:        <   Buffer, subtree/region restriction
    --------------------------------        >   Remove restriction
    a   Agenda for current week or day      e   Export agenda views
    t   List of all TODO entries            T   Entries with special TODO kwd
    m   Match a TAGS/PROP/TODO query        M   Like m, but only TODO entries"

Comment: @aartist - you solved it !!! Will accept your answer once I am allowed to . Thank you, thank you, thank you !

Comment: and the pressing `a`, I expect gives the list with no entries, right? could you try the different options from the agenda menu? could you also try assigning a date to a header with `C-c .` and see if that shows in the list?

Comment: @manandearth - you're correct. Thanks for the follow up. aartist has already solved the problem for me. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @aartist: please make your comment an answer.

Comment: BTW, `org-timeline` is obsolete. It was removed from the org-mode source base in Dec. 2016. It might still be available in the version you are using, but when you upgrade it's going to disappear.

Comment: @Nick - I agree. emacs26 doesn't have
`org-timelime`
(sad cos I love the feature) but
`C-u 365 C-c a a`
gives a diary for 365 days and if we have
`(org-agenda-start-day "-60d")
(org-agenda-start-on-weekday nil)
(org-agenda-include-diary t)`
I think it gives me something analogous to org-timeline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check : `C-h v org-agenda-files`. If your file is not there then, while your  file is opened in the buffer, use  `M-x org-agenda-file-to-front`.  Now try `M-x org-agenda`.  You can check `C-h v org-agenda-files` again and you will find your file there.